# Can a website with a product menu, which spans over multiple pages (1 of 14, 2 of 14) displaying 20 items per page, be viewed as one long-form scroll?

Tags: browser, viewer

This seems like a unique request but I was attempting to view a website's menu, which spans over 14 pages, as a single webpage that could be printed as such.  It would save the added work of having to print each page individually and the single layout format would be easier to view. I'm curious if anyone else has thought of this or is looking for similar solution. Doesn't seem like something that is necessary but it would make things much easier. Thank you

Comment: Though there are ways to download a whole website (https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-do-i-download-an-entire-website-for-offline-reading/), with the limitation that recursion and outside links could create a monster, I know of no way to print an entire site. You could manually capture the3 HTML of 14 pages (or 14 images) and paste them together.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you're looking for is called "infinite scrolling", here's an example [GitHub repository](https://github.com/metafizzy/infinite-scroll), which you can use to deploy from the web design perspective.

However, if I'm reading your OP correctly, I'm getting the sense that you are inquiring from the end-user perspective.  The inclusion of this feature when viewing the website as-is would be entirely dependent upon the website owner's/designer's development and deployment, and whether or not they decided to include such a feature.  On some sites, you may need to create a user account and view your account settings to change page display preferences.

If they didn't, there would be two avenues I would suggest pursuing:

1. **Send them your feedback and request.**
   The fact that their menu spans across 14 pages and is a hassle to compile together is *very much relevant* UX feedback to their organization, and in most cases they would welcome such user feedback.  Further, if you have a need for a special report, view, catalog, or other such document, in most cases they'll have someone who is able to generate that for you, given that they stand to gain monetary benefits in exchange for providing you such service.  Even if they do not, it doesn't hurt to ask!  There are many nice people out there who wouldn't mind fulfilling simple requests like this regardless of whether or not you'll be committing a subsequent sales order.
2. **Take matters into your own hands.**
   If things don't pan out going the above route, you can always just take matters into your own hands.  If you have the relevant experience and knowledge, you can always inject your own .js via, e.g., [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) scripts.  You can also print/save/capture the individual pages and stitch them together programmatically through, e.g., [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php).  There are also other extensions or methods you can use, it largely depends on what you're trying to achieve exactly and what functional criteria come with that.

You can always edit your question or create additional ones with more specific details and requirements, but I hope this at least give you a better idea on how to proceed from here.